# Java reading cyrrilic CSV file, writing strange characters

Tags: java, csv, encoding

This is my java code

(and the whole project has UTF-8 encoding)

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getCSVContent(String filepath) throws Exception { 
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filepath));
            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
            String[] nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < nextLine.length; i++) {
                    list.add(nextLine[i]);
                }
                array.add(list);
            }
            reader.close();
            return array;
        }
```

This is my CSV File:

```
Place1  ул. "Цанко Церковски" No37  Category1   bar Bulgaria    Sofia   310-808-5243
Place 2 ул."Ген. Гурко" No 6    Category2   bar Bulgaria    Sofia   415-846-1688
Place 3 ул. "Гео Милев" No 18   Category3   bar Bulgaria    Sofia   720-318-9049
```

And this is the output

instead of 
ул. "Цанко Церковски" No37, for example

I get:
��. ���������, ��. ����� ��������� ����� �

It probably has something to do with the encoding of the CSV file, But Im not sure how can I view/change that and whether I should use Word or Open Office?

Also, may I change the way Java reads such files so even if they are in the wrong encoding, Java fixes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite possibly the problem:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filepath));
```

`FileReader` always uses the platform-default encoding. I prefer to use `InputStreamReader` wrapped around a `FileInputStream`, as then you can specify the encoding:

```
try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(filepath)) {
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did that, but the output is the same :( Could it be the encoding of the file?

Comment: @J.Kowalski: Well yes - I wrote the above assuming it really *is* UTF-8. You need to find out the encoding of the file, and make sure you specify that encoding as the second argument to `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: well, the file had another encoding. the worst thing is, I changed the encoding to UTF-8 and also the code the way you suggested and Im still getting the same output

Comment: I actually fixed this by opening the document with notepad.exe and changing the encoding there. Looks like Excel's change of encoding wasnt successfull.

Answer (score 2):

you can explicitly set encoding like here

`new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), encoding));`