# How to read csv file from url with utf-8 chars in java

Tags: java, csv, read.csv

How to correctly read a .csv file in java? I have a utf-8 encoded file but cannot read certain characters correctly.

[image]

My code:

```
String link = new String("https://stat.gov.pl/download/gfx/portalinformacyjny/pl/defaultstronaopisowa/4741/1/1/miesieczne_wskazniki_cen_towarow_i_uslug_konsumpcyjnych_od_1982_roku.csv");

URL url = new URL(link);

BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String i;
while ((i = read.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(i);
read.close();
```

Comment: What prints out when you run this code, and how is it different from what you are expecting?

Comment: Also please add the results and minimal reproducible example in the post rather than linking to it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java reading cyrrilic CSV file, writing strange characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573313/java-reading-cyrrilic-csv-file-writing-strange-characters)

Comment: Have you verified the input is UTF-8? Open the file with a text editor where you can mandate a character encoding. Or open with a hex editor to view the octets yourself. I would guess the file is *not* actually in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: What prints out when you run this code:  I added a screenshot to the post; Generally there is a problem with signs such as: żółćąśó

Comment: Is this Polish text?

Comment: Please tell us what happens when you remove the charset argument from the ```InputStreamReader```  ctor

Comment: The file was not encoded in utf-8 but in ANSI; I changed StandardCharsets.UTF_8 to "Cp1252" and it works; thank you for the hint and sorry for the inconvenience :)

Comment: I think you might find it's ```Windows-1250```

Answer (score 0):

> `https://stat.gov.pl/download/gfx/portalinformacyjny/pl/defaultstronaopisowa/4741/1/1/miesieczne_wskazniki_cen_towarow_i_uslug_konsumpcyjnych_od_1982_roku.csv`

**That is not UTF-8!**

Hence why your code fails. You assumed it was UTF-8. It isn't. Also, the headers tell you it's 'binary' (it really isn't, but the point is, the server isn't giving you a charset either), so you have to guess. It's probably Windows-1250.

This byte sequence is in that CSV:

> 57 61 72 74 6F 9C E6

The last 2 are 'interesting' (the other are in the ASCII block so identical is just about every encoding). So that reads Warto?? where the ? are the interesting parts. If this is [Windows-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250), it spells Wartość. Google tells me that's polish.

So, you need to do three things to fix this:

1. Stop assuming everything is UTF_8.
2. Learn mojibake detective skills. This involves downloading stuff raw, using hex editors, hunting for things that seem like half of a familiar term (like Warto..), and then looking up likely code pages and checking if the bytes match up to what you thought it should be. It's a drag. There are no shortcuts for it, when the server doesn't tell you what the encoding is, mojibake detective skills are your only option.
3. Replace `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` with `"Windows-1250"`, which I'm pretty sure works on any JVM. If not, oof. You'd have to write that codepage yourself and register it as a charset.